# Pusher Doesn't Broadcast on Private Channels -PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I have set up Pusher and Laravel Echo for my app to notify users on some event firings.

I have tested to see whether setup is working by broadcasting on a "Public Channel" and successfully saw that is works.

Here is the event itself:

```
class ItemUpdated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

  public $item;

  public function __construct(Item $item)
  {
      $this->item = $item;
  }

  public function broadcastOn()
  {
      return new Channel('items');
  }
}
```

Public channel:

```
Broadcast::channel('items', function ($user, $item) {
  return true;
});
```

app/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js:

```
import  Echo from 'laravel-echo';
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'my_key',
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true
});
```

And Laravel Echo registration: (it is in the "head" section of my main layout that event firing view extends from.)

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    window.Laravel = {'csrfToken': '{{csrf_token()}}'}

    window.Echo.channel('items')
    .listen('ItemUpdated', function(e) {
        console.log("It is working:)");
    });

</script>
</head>
```

Now, this setup works for public channel broadcasting, but when i try to broadcast on a private channel, i get

```
  //updated "ItemUpdated" event broadcastOn() method
  public function broadcastOn()
  {
      return new PrivateChannel('items');
  }

//updated laravel echo registering
<script>
window.Laravel = {'csrfToken': '{{csrf_token()}}'}

window.Echo.private('items')
.listen('ItemUpdated', function(e) {
    console.log("It is working:)");
});
```

```
 //console logged error
Pusher couldn't get the auth user from :myapp 500
```

I have checked the outgoing network requests from developer console and find out pusher is trying to "POST" to

```
http://localhost:8000/broadcast/auth
```

but it gets a 500 error code.

Thought that might help figure out the problem.

What should i do ?

Comment: It's a `500` error. Check your logs.

Comment: yes, but since my server is working properly for public broadcasting, i don't know where the problem is

Comment: As stated above. Check your logs. What do they say?

Comment: Log infoPusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 500

Comment: That's what your server's error log says, or pusher's error log?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So i figured out how should i implement private channel listening and got it working.

My mistake was in wildcard choice.

I was telling it to use the authenticated user id as a wildcard instead of item id that changes are applied to.

Therefore, this below channel registration was always returning false and was causing Pusher to throw 500 auth couldn't found.

```
  Broadcast::channel('items.{item}', function ($user, \App\Item $item) {
    return $user->id === $item->user_id;
});
```

## So, here is the working version:

**Event being broadcasted:**

```
//ItemUpdated event

class ItemUpdated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
   use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

   public $item;

   public function __construct(Item $item)
   {
       $this->item = $item;
   }

   public function broadcastOn()
   {
       return new PrivateChannel('items.'.$this->item->id);
   }
}
```

**Channel registration:**

```
app\routes\channels.php    

Broadcast::channel('items.{item}', function ($user, \App\Item $item) {
    return $user->id === $item->user_id;
});
```

**Laravel Echo registration:**

```
<head>

<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">


<script>
    window.Laravel = {'csrfToken': '{{csrf_token()}}'}

    window.Echo.private(`items.{{{$item->id}}}`)
    .listen('ItemUpdated', function(e) {
        console.log("It is working!");
    });

</script>
```

Thank you all for pointers.